# How to enable Help page with basicHttp binding?

Tags: c#, wcf, binding, web-config, wcf-binding

I tried to enable Help page for basicHttpBinding  but i am getting following errors

```
The endpoint at 'http://localhost:52568/address.svc/ws' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.
```

I guess the above error is because of `<webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>` is only for webHttp Binding..

Now my exact need is i want to enable Help page for basicHttpBinding .how to do it ?

here my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MCDThirdPartyService.Store">  
    <endpoint address="ms" binding="basicHttpBinding"   contract="MCDThirdPartyService.IStore" behaviorConfiguration="MDS_Service.LoginAspNetAjaxBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>    

  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MCDThirdPartyService.address">
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MCDThirdPartyService.Iaddress" behaviorConfiguration="MDS_Service.LoginAspNetAjaxBehavior"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MCDThirdPartyService.Configuration">
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MCDThirdPartyService.IConfiguration" behaviorConfiguration="MDS_Service.LoginAspNetAjaxBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MCDThirdPartyService.Order">
    <endpoint address="ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MCDThirdPartyService.IOrder" behaviorConfiguration="MDS_Service.LoginAspNetAjaxBehavior" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>


 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>        
    <behavior name="MDS_Service.LoginAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>   
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: provide that help facility at your consumer end rather.

Comment: you are saying to enable help page in client side? but the think is, my side i want help page.is it Possible?

Comment: I don't think so but you can enable tracing and message logging though.

Comment: but tracing and message logging wont give a APIs list